# Solr Suggester not returning multiple terms

Tags: solr

I'm trying to setup the suggester component, but I'm not getting the results I expect.  I would expect that I get back phrases, but I'm getting back single words, and some don't even exist.  The data looks like the following:

```
Fullerton, CA 
Fulton, NY 
Fultondale, AL 
Fulton County, GA
```

My Schema file looks like:

```xml
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>

<fieldtype name="phrase_suggest" class="solr.TextField">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory"
            pattern="([^\p{L}\p{M}\p{N}\p{Cs}]*[\p{L}\p{M}\p{N}\p{Cs}\_]+:)|([^\p{L}\p{M}\p{N}\p{Cs}])+"
            replacement=" " replace="all"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldtype>
```

My solrconfig looks like:

```xml
<searchComponent class="solr.SpellCheckComponent" name="suggest">
<lst name="spellchecker">
  <str name="name">suggest</str>
  <str name="classname">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.Suggester</str>
  <str name="lookupImpl">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.tst.TSTLookup</str>
  <str name="field">Location</str>
</lst>
<!-- specify a fieldtype using keywordtokenizer + lowercase + cleanup -->
<str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">phrase_suggest</str>
</searchComponent>

<queryConverter name="queryConverter"  class="org.apache.solr.spelling.SuggestQueryConverter"/>

<requestHandler class="org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler" name="/suggest">
<lst name="defaults">
  <str name="spellcheck">true</str>
  <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">suggest</str>
  <str name="spellcheck.count">5</str>
  <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
</lst>
<arr name="components">
  <str>suggest</str>
</arr>
```

The result looks like:

```xml
<response>
    <lst name="responseHeader">
        <int name="status">0</int>
        <int name="QTime">2</int>
    </lst>
    <lst name="spellcheck">
    <lst name="suggestions">
    <lst name="ful">
        <int name="numFound">5</int>
        <int name="startOffset">0</int>
        <int name="endOffset">3</int>
        <arr name="suggestion">
            <str>fuld</str>
            <str>full</str>
            <str>fuller</str>
            <str>fulton</str>
            <str>fultondale</str>
        </arr>
    </lst>
    <str name="collation">fuld</str>
    </lst>
    </lst>
</response>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should remove the analyzer type=query from the "text_general"

should be something like :

```
`<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>`
```